# Is there a way to use OracleDB with Node 10.15?

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I am limited in my cloud environment to Node v10.15.x and I need 10+ for experimental-modules. However, when I try to install OracleDB I get...

```
oracledb ERR! NJS-069: node-oracledb 4.1.0 requires Node.js 10.16 or later
oracledb ERR! An older node-oracledb version may work with Node.js v10.15.0
```

If I try downgrading OracleDB to 3.1.2 it requires Node 8 so this won't work either.

```
oracledb ERR! NJS-067: a pre-built node-oracledb binary was not found for Node.js v12.1.0 (NODE_MODULE_VERSION=72) on win32 x64
oracledb ERR! Try compiling node-oracledb source code using https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#github
```

Is there a way to get oracledb to work with Node 10.15?

### Update

This seems to not be clear so let me be explicit. Locally I have Node 12 this works fine with v 4.1.0 of OracleDB. However, this doen't work when I try to upload to Cloud Foundry because the version is 10.15. When I downgrade to 3.1.2 OracleDB it no longer compiles locally and won't deploy to Gaia because it needs a version of node that is less than 9 and we need greater than 9 for other features.

Answer (score 1):

There were prebuilt [node-oracledb 3.1.2 binaries for Node 6, 8, 10, and 11](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/releases/tag/v3.1.2).
Your text above says you want to use Node.js 10.15 but your example shows you tried to install on Node.js 12: `Node.js v12.1.0 (NODE_MODULE_VERSION=72)`, hence your error.  Make sure Node.js is the desired version 10, and try again with node-oracledb 3.1.2.

If you want to use node-oracledb 4 with Node.js 10.15, then compile from source code.  The message is clear.

But you really should upgrade Node.js to a later version and get all the Node.js security fixes.

Update to address comment: if npm can't access the npmjs.com repo, you may be able to manually download https://registry.npmjs.com/oracledb/-/oracledb-3.1.2.tgz and install from a local file e.g. `npm install /file/path/to/oracledb-3.1.2.tgz` or in package.json use a dependency `"oracledb": "file:/file/path/to/oracledb-3.1.2.tgz"`, similar to https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#selfhost.

Comment: Sorry I looked at the wrong version of this I thought it was my company specific version. The problem is the 2nd message is the version where I use OracleDB 3 and try to deploy to 10. The problem is even if I try to deploy using 10 it still provides the same message but it isn't supported because we do not provide the proper node binaries checked into our proprietary repo. Also software is controlled and GCC and Make are not provided to allow the ability to compile from source.

Comment: I would also remove the downvote but you have to edit first

Comment: If your site usage is locked down you may have to work with your IT teams to get usable versions of Node.js & node-oracledb installed.  However if can do a manual download and install from a file, that may help. I updated the answer with the steps.

Comment: By the way, this kind of issue should be rare in future, since the refactoring in node-oracledb 4.0 to use N-API gives much better Node.js version independence.